# coordinate conversion javascript library Pro4js wrong results

Tags: javascript, coordinate-transformation, proj4js

I am trying to use [Proj4js](http://proj4js.org/), to convert to and from a couple(sweref99tm, rt90, kkj3, wgs84) of coordinates. For some reason I am getting wrong results. [Here](http://jsbin.com/magacodimu/1/edit?js,output) are my codes which result into wrong results, please check and help me fix it.

Thanks.

Links:

[MyCode](http://jsbin.com/magacodimu/1/edit?js,output)

[Proj4Js Library](http://proj4js.org/)

[Online calculator for verification](http://latlong.mellifica.se/)

Comment: looking at your code, you SAY you're trying to convert WGS84(60,20) => SWEREF99tm, the code actually tries to proj4(wgs,swe,[60,18]) ... 18 is not 20

Comment: yes, according to the library documentation the format is proj4(from, to, [lat,lon]), so from wgs84 to sweref99tm. I have done both ways(to and from) but both results are wrong

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
The problem was with the order of [lat, lon]. Changing from

```
proj4(wgs,swe,[60,18])
```

to

```
proj4(wgs,swe,[18,60])
```

solved the problem.
Thanks.